# Is it possible to use BigQuery to find when people request a website?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out at what time people request content from a website (such as 'www.netflix.com'), do any of the avalible reports contain this data? If so how would I access it?

I've had a look around and can't see a table that has this data. Would anywhere else store it?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant reports that available in BigQuery, I would suggest exploring [BigQuery Public Datasets.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data) At the moment I do not see any website access datasets but might still be useful for your reference.